# I need a regex that matches numbers depending on a variable

Tags: java, regex, match

i'm having some problems when trying to find a regex for my code. Here it is:

```
Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

    //this is the variable
    int s = 4;

    String input = "";
    String bregex = "[1-9][0-9]{1," + (s*s) + "}";
    boolean cfgmatch = false;

    while(cfgmatch == false){

        input = key.next();

        Pattern cfgbp = Pattern.compile(bregex);

        Matcher bm = cfgbp.matcher(input);

        if(bm.matches()){

            System.out.println("working");

        }
        else{

            System.out.println("not working");

        }

    }
```

I'm trying to make a regex to resrict a number of cells in a board. cells number can't be higer than board's space, which is "s*s".

Example: If board's size is 4, the input can be from 1 to 16, if it's 5, from 1 to 25, etc...

Board size can only be from 1 to 9.

I've written that while to ask for another number in case of failing the input.

Comment: Why are you using a String tool, regex, for what sounds like is best handled through a simple numeric boolean check? It looks like you're trying to use a screwdriver to saw through planks of wood -- that you're using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: I guess [Zawinski](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) meant situations like these when he wrote: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems."

Answer (score 1):

**Be Careful with Regular Expressions**

While a regular expression could potentially work for this, it's really better designed to handle pattern matching as opposed to arithmetic operations. Your current regular expression would generate `s*s` digits, which isn't going to be defining the range you are looking for :

```
// If s = 4, then this regular express will match any string that begins with a 1 and 
// would allow any values from 1-99999999999999999 as opposed to the 1-16 you are expecting
String bregex = "[1-9][0-9]{1,16}";
```

**Consider a Simpler Approach**

You may be better off avoiding it if you are going to be comparing your input numerically to another value (i.e. is this number less than x) :

```
// Is your number less than the largest possible square value?
if(parseInt(input) <= s*s){
   // Valid
}
else {
   // Invalid
}
```

Comment: No need even for the `parseInt`, as `Scanner` has a `nextInt()` method.

Comment: That's true Sam. I was just providing a very generic example (i.e. `input` in this scenario could be any string input).

Comment: Thanks, you really helped me. A condition is simpler that making a patter it's true.. this things happens when you write for hours haha